# To determine the rate of convergence of given sequences.

Tags: numerical-methods

Determine the rate of convergence of each sequence and numerically determine which of the following sequences approaches 1 faster.

$$\lim_{x\to0}  \frac{ sinx^2}{x^2} versus \lim_{x\to0} \frac{(sinx)^2}{x^2}$$  **

I just found out the rate of convergence for this sequence
$\lim_{x\to0}  \frac{ sinx^2}{x^2}$.

For this,
I used Taylor's theorem 
$\frac{sinx^2}{x^2} = 1- \frac{x^4}{6} \sin £ $

for some £ between 0 and x.

Then I found the rate of convergence to be $ O(x^4)$. 
Just need help to find rate of convergence of other sequence.

Textbook i am using:- Brain Bradie
 A friendly introduction to numerical analysis.

Comment: The other taylor series is $1-1/3x^2+2/45x^4+O(x^6)$

Comment: What is meant by "numerically" ? The easiest way would be inserting the values $x=10^{-n}$ with $n=1,2,3,\cdots$

Comment: I edited my question. Do you mean rate of convergence of other sequence is $O(x^6)$

Comment: No, I would say the rates are $O(x^2)$ and $O(x^4)$

Comment: I need the steps in detail according to definition of rate of convergence of a sequence. Please

Comment: I am not sure and do not want to claim something wrong. But it seems logical that the smallest non-constant power is the rate of convergence. No idea however, how this rate should be determined numerically. We could perhaps compare the rates numerically, but I do not know a reliable numerical method for this either.

Comment: No. This rate need not be shown numerically. I have to compare the rates numerically. Let me show you how I used the definition to find rate of one sequence. Give me some time to post the way.

Comment: The problem is that one sequence could approach faster at the beginning, but on the long run, the other could approach faster. So, we never can be sure which function approaches faster overall.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{sinx^2}{x^2} = 1- \frac{x^4}{6} \sin £ $

Rate of convergence of a sequence:- 
Let ${P_n}$ be a sequence that convergences to a number P. If there exists a sequence ${B_n}$
 which converges to zero and a positive constant K such that
$|P_n - P| \le |B_n|$ then the sequence convergences to P with rate of convergence $O(B_n)$.

So I found out $K= \frac{1}{6}$ and $B=x^4$.
Similarly i need such steps for other sequence.